# Removing double dot after fig. number

Tags: captions

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} to make the figure looks like this Fig. 1. Blind text caption

However a double dot appears like this example Fig. 1: , I want to remove this double dots and make it single such that it looks like this Fig. 1. Blind text caption

Worth mentioning that I have to use \usepackage{caption} for setup the width of certain captions of figures

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `labelsep=period` option of the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{Caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]